# Restart jetty via Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jetty, hudson, restart

I want restart a jetty server after building my webapp successfully. Unfortunately it does not work. I put following as a Post-Build-Step in my Jenkins job:

> /Users/Shared/jetty/bin/jetty.sh restart &

The jetty logs show me that the server has started but immediately shutdown. While the Jenkin job finished the jetty shutdowns as well i guess.

I use Jenkins v1.545!

stdError.log says:

> 2014-01-16 09:14:24.096:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7516a8f3{/MRSServer,...
>   2014-01-16 09:14:24.108:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6bcd9bfc{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7050}
>   2014-01-16 09:14:45.626:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:Thread-1: Stopped ServerConnector@6bcd9bfc{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7050}
>   2014-01-16 09:14:45.627:INFO:oejwc.WebSocketClient:Thread-1: Stopped org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient@7785b73c
>   2014-01-16 09:14:45.633:INFO:MRSServer:Thread-1: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext

I tried this one as well:

> nohup /Users/Shared/jetty/bin/jetty.sh restart &

But this brings this error:

> nohup: can't detach from console: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Any advise how the keep the jetty server alive while the Jenkins job finished?

Comment: What's in the log that caused the server to shutdown immediately?

Comment: nohup command & should work and run in the background. I have used it before and it worked. What version is your Jenkins?

Comment: added the info above!